# Joomla Capatcha not working

Tags: php, joomla

I have a Joomla 2.5.9 site.  The user registration has a capatcha on it.

After awhile my users told me that it was no longer showing.  It would just say "Capatcha" but not show the graphic.

I did some searching online and saw that I needed to change the paths in the file "plugins\captcha\recaptcha\recaptcha.php"

The tips I've found recommended things like changing this:

```
const RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER = "http://api.recaptcha.net";  
const RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";  
const RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER = "api-verify.recaptcha.net";
```

to this

```
 const RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";  
 const RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";  
 const RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER = "api-verify.recaptcha.net";
```

Source : http://click4joomla.blogspot.com/2014/01/recaptcha-is-not-working-on-joomla.html

After I've made changes like that, the capatcha would work, but after a little bit of time it'd stop showing again.  And I'd have to make another similar change to these paths in this file.  This has happened about 3 times now.

Is there a more permanent solution I make? My control panel is saying my Joomla is up to date and my public and private keys are correct.  What is the proper way to fix this?

Comment: Have you reviewed Joomla bug fixes from 2.5.10 through 2.5.22 to see if this was a known bug which was fixed?  I would start there as a lot of bugs were still present in your current version.

Comment: @Brian Bolli From the articles I read I didn't think this was a bug issue, but a matter of google changing the path to their recaptcha api.  I could be wrong though and will look into that

Comment: Ok your control panel is WRONG: your Joomla is so old it most likely was hacked already. Go to joomla.org, download the Update package for 2.5.24, install it via ftp, go to extension manager / database and press Fix, you can't have such an old installation it's just asking for trouble. btw it will also solve your captcha issues as Lodder pointed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **verify server** is still incorrect. You should change it from this:

```
const RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER = "api-verify.recaptcha.net";
```

to this:

```
const RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER = "www.google.com";
```

This bug was fixed in a later Joomla version when the recaptcha library was moved iver to Google.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out.  Do you know if the API Server and API Secure Server are still correct or were those changed too? I looked for Joomla's fixes but still came up with those

Comment: The **API Server** and **API Secure Server** also changed but you have defined the correct values in your second code snippet in your question. I would strongly suggest updating to Joomla 2.5.24 at the very least as there are a large amount of bug fixes.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help.  I figured since the control panel said "up to date" I had the most recent bug fixes.  I'll update as suggested.  Thanks to Riccardo Zorn and Brian Bolli as well